# How to fix error: expected unqualified-id in C++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++17

I am not getting why I am getting errors in these lines.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class One
{
   public:
    virtual void disp() { cout << " Class One"; }
};
class Two : public One
{
   public:
    void disp() { cout << "Class Two"; }
};
int main(void)
{
    One *op = new Two;
    op->disp();
    One & or = *op;  // error: expected unqualified-id before 'or' token
    or.disp();       // error: expected primary-expression before 'or' token and
                     // error: expected primary-expression before '.' token
    return 0;
}
```

I tried a few things but couldn't seem to resolve this error.

Comment: Try changing `or` name to something else.

Comment: "or" is a reserved word, and is a logical operator. It means the same as `||`.